# Сортировка данных бд

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, сортировка

Имеется база данных sqlite, в которой одна таблица(см. скриншот)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести 1 поле рецепт и все поля ingridient относящиеся к нему, если запрос совпадает с ингредиентом. Например: запрос = "Вода" -> Вывести 1 поле Морс Черничный и все его ингредиенты. Составил такой запрос `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM receptes
WHERE ingridient = "запрос";` Всё ли правильно я сделал?

Comment: А distinct зачем ? Обычно с `*` он не используется, потому что хоть одно поле у другой записи но окажется не таким как было у предыдущей и значит строка будет уникальна и distinct ничего в выдаче не изменит, кроме увеличения времени выполнения

Comment: @Mike ,да ты прав. Я просто хотел добиться вывода только 1 поля recept

Comment: тогда укажите это одно поле, вместо `*`, а distinct по необходимости, если надо подавить одинаковые значения при выводе

Comment: @Mike А как тогда мне выводить ингредиенты?

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить, потому что вы не привели структуру таблиц. А вообще зачем вы спрашиваете правильный ли такой запрос, проверка занимает 5 секунд, если выдает то, что ожидается, то вероятно правильный